# Can't call success function

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm developing a Backbone Node.js with Express.js app. I'm trying to trigger a function after receiving a response from my server like the code bellow:

**mainView.js**

```
...

user: null,

initialize: function () {
     _.bindAll(this, 'registerSuccess', 'loginSuccess');
     this.user = new userModel();
}

registerSuccess: function () {
     this.user.auth({
          success: this.loginSuccess
     });
});

loginSuccess: function () {
    console.log('loginSuccess');
}
```

**userModel.js**

```
  ...  

, auth: function (options) {
     $.ajax({
          url: 'users/auth'
        , type: 'post'
     }, options);
})
```

**app.js**

```
var api = require('./routes/apiController');

app.post('/users/auth', api.userAuth);
```

**apiController.js**

```
exports.userAuth = function (req, res) {

    return res.send( { 
       status: 200
    });

}
```

**I´m getting the response:**

[image]

But it doesn't print the `console.log('loginSuccess')` sentence from this function.

Comment: Maybe the typo is not in your original code, but in the mainView.js it says `loginSuccess; function () {` instead of `loginSuccess: function () {`, it should be a colon, not a semicolon.

Comment: No, it isn´t. This is an edit error, sorry.

Comment: It works, i had to read more about $.ajax, I read now jquery docs and it says: jQuery.ajax(url, [settings]) or jQuery.ajax([settings]), where [settings] is a plain object key-value. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to call [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

1. [`jQuery.ajax(url, settings)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings)
2. [`jQuery.ajax(settings)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

In the first case, `url` **must** be a string and `settings` is an optional object; in the second case, `settings` is again an optional object. You're calling `$.ajax` with two objects:

```
auth: function (options) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'users/auth'
      , type: 'post'
    }, options);
}
```

Since the first argument is not a string, `$.ajax` will use the second calling form and ignore `options` completely. You probably want to use [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) to merge the arguments:

```
$.ajax(_({
    url: 'users/auth'
  , type: 'post'
}).extend(options));
```

Or [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) if you want to avoid accidentally overwriting `url` and `type`:

```
$.ajax(_({
    url: 'users/auth'
  , type: 'post'
}).defaults(options));
```

Or, since you only have two things, just stuff them in manually:

```
options      = _(options).clone(); // Avoid accidentally messing with the argument.
options.url  = 'users/auth';
options.type = 'post';
$.ajax(options);
```